# Efficient way to get latest/newest version of versioned time series per group/aggregate function using TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

We are moving to TimescaleDB and have migrated some large tables with more than 400 million rows holding versioned time series forecasts.

The structure of the table is the following whereas `dt_start_utc` holds the actual date of the forecast and `version_utc` the issue date of the forecast (the newer, the closer to the actual forecast date):

```
sandbox_cord=# \d+ fc_power_raw_import_normalized
                                    Table "public.fc_power_raw_import_normalized"
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
dt_start_utc         | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
fc_id                | integer                     |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
fc_kwh               | integer                     |           |          |         | plain   |              |
fc_power_supplier_id | integer                     |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
fc_power_type_id     | integer                     |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
version_utc          | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "fc_power_raw_import_normalized2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (dt_start_utc, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id, version_utc)
    "fc_power_raw_import_normalize2_dt_start_utc_fc_id_fc_power_s_id" btree (dt_start_utc DESC, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id, version_utc DESC)
    "fc_power_raw_import_normalize2_dt_start_utc_fc_power_supplie_id" btree (dt_start_utc DESC, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id)
    "fc_power_raw_import_normalized2_dt_start_utc_idx" btree (dt_start_utc DESC)
    "fc_power_raw_import_normalized2_version_utc_idx" btree (version_utc DESC)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON fc_power_raw_import_normalized2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Child tables: _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2334_chunk,
            _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2335_chunk,
            _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2336_chunk,
            _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2337_chunk,
            _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2338_chunk,
            _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_2339_chunk
Access method: heap
...
```

And here are some values:

```
sandbox_cord=# SELECT * FROM fc_power_raw_import_normalized ORDER BY fc_id ASC LIMIT 25;
    dt_start_utc     | fc_id | fc_kwh | fc_power_supplier_id | fc_power_type_id |     version_utc
---------------------+-------+--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    167 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-23 00:27:03
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    150 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-23 01:12:37
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    132 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-23 07:11:42
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    144 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-23 13:12:11
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    161 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-23 19:13:05
2020-08-27 00:00:00 |     9 |    166 |                    5 |                1 | 2020-08-24 01:11:53
...
```

Now I want to get the newest version of the timeseries per group (`fc_id`) which I get with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fc_power_raw_import_normalized
WHERE  (dt_start_utc, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id, version_utc) IN (
    SELECT
    dt_start_utc, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id, MAX(version_utc) version_utc
    FROM
    fc_power_raw_import_normalized
    WHERE
    dt_start_utc > now() - INTERVAL '2 weeks'
    GROUP BY
    dt_start_utc, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id
)
AND dt_start_utc > now() - INTERVAL '2 weeks'
ORDER by fc_id, dt_start_utc, version_utc;
```

**UPDATE** or with the following query using TimescaleDBs [last()](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/last/#sample-usage)  function:

```
SELECT
dt_start_utc,
    fc_id,
    fc_power_supplier_id,
    fc_power_type_id,
    last(fc_kwh, version_utc) AS fc_kwh_last
FROM fc_power_raw_import_normalized
WHERE dt_start_utc > now () - INTERVAL '2 weeks'
GROUP BY dt_start_utc, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id
ORDER BY dt_start_utc ASC, fc_id ASC;
```

This yields:

```
   dt_start_utc     | fc_id | fc_kwh | fc_power_supplier_id | fc_power_type_id |     version_utc
---------------------+-------+--------+----------------------+------------------+---------------------
2021-10-12 16:45:00 |    19 |     99 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 16:45:00 |    19 |     99 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 17:00:00 |    19 |    100 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 17:00:00 |    19 |    100 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 17:15:00 |    19 |    103 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 17:15:00 |    19 |    103 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 17:30:00 |    19 |    105 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 17:30:00 |    19 |    105 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 17:45:00 |    19 |    108 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 17:45:00 |    19 |    108 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 18:00:00 |    19 |    108 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 18:00:00 |    19 |    108 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 18:15:00 |    19 |    105 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 13:13:50
2021-10-12 18:15:00 |    19 |    105 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 13:14:47
2021-10-12 18:30:00 |    19 |     82 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 18:28:47
2021-10-12 18:30:00 |    19 |     82 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 18:29:59
2021-10-12 18:45:00 |    19 |     82 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 18:28:47
2021-10-12 18:45:00 |    19 |     82 |                    4 |                2 | 2021-10-12 18:29:59
2021-10-12 19:00:00 |    19 |     81 |                    4 |                1 | 2021-10-12 18:28:47
...
```

But this is actually pretty slow e. g. it takes ~77 seconds to calculate this for 3 months and way more for longer horizons.

I have tried different variants of this query now using `INNER JOIN` or window functions and also added different indices according to [this article](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/). But none of these approaches has brought up a significant increase in performance.

Another approach was to work [continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts/continuous-aggregates/#quick-start) which require a time bucket to be defined (see this question: [Continuous aggregates in postgres/timescaledb requires time_bucket-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843670/continuous-aggregates-in-postgres-timescaledb-requires-time-bucket-function)) and does not seem to be suitable here. The underlying chunk size was another thing I have changed but also without significant improvements.

So far, when related to this table structure and query, the performance of TimescaleDB is not much better than our optimized "conventional" relational database which is MariaDB and I expected a dedicated time series database to come of with a better default performance.

Now my question is simple: How can I efficiently get the latest/newest version of versioned time series per group/aggregate function using TimescaleDB and this table structure?

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Versioned time-series like this are hard. Which timestamp is your partitioning key? What other queries are you doing? Are you mostly getting the newest one? Are you fully committed to this model or are you open to other data models?

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for your answer.The partitioning key is `dt_start_utc`. Queries are mostly for newer values but sometimes on the entire table for some historical analysis. I am not fully comitted to this data model but it would of course be easier like this. Alternative approaches and ideas are welcome!

Comment: I meanwhile found a more performant query formulation using TimescaleDBs `last()` function. It seems to scale slightly better and I am doing some tests at the moment.

Comment: Would compression be beneficial for these kinds of tables and usage scenarios?

Comment: Also, a partitioning on the `version_utc` field might be beneficial, if I get you right?

Comment: Okay. So, as I understand it, you have a version_utc, and that's going to be constant for a large number of values of dt_start_utc? is that right?

Comment: And can you add in your `last` query to the question? 
When you say they're for newer values are they for newer values of dt_start_utc or newer values of version utc? when do you use old versions? How often are new versions made? How many versions are there?

Comment: Yes, `version_utc` is constant for many values as the forecasts are updated synchronously for different sites which are in column `fc_id` and also limited. I have added my `last()` query to the question and it delivers the same results as the `INNER JOIN`. There is an `1:n` relation between `dt_start_utc` and `version_utc` meaning that a specific point in time can have different forecasts (tracked via `version_utc`).

Comment: So there are from `1...50` different `version_utc` values for a single value of `dt_start_utc` but as `version_utc` holds the forecast version for `dt_start_utc` these will always be "older" i.e. before. Updates come in every couple of hours and old versions are used only sometimes.

Comment: Are you ever looking for things from the latest but they're not actually the same version? I'm also wondering why you're using a timestamp rather than an int or something...it seems like keeping a separate table with version ids or somethign like that might be easier and running your query so that you just get the last version id and query by it would make sense to me...

Comment: (If you like that idea I can build on it in an actual answer and flesh it out a bit...)

Comment: I now found a solution which I have posted. Nonethess, thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you found a way to do it well!

Answer (score 1):

I now found a solution using [Continuous Aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts/continuous-aggregates/) (with Real Time Aggregation as default behaviour). It might have been obvious but nonetheless took me a while to discover. So I will share it here in order to help someone else with the same problem.

The query is slightly adapted but the example shows the general approach.

Example:

1. Create a continuous aggregate:

   ```
   CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW latest_forecast_15_min
   WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
   SELECT
   time_bucket('15 minutes', dt_start_utc) AS dt_start,
   fc_id,
   fc_power_supplier_id,
   fc_power_type_id,
   last(fc_kwh, version_utc) AS fc_kwh_last
   FROM fc_power_raw_import_normalized
   WHERE dt_start_utc > now () - INTERVAL '2 weeks'
   GROUP BY dt_start, fc_id, fc_power_supplier_id, fc_power_type_id;
   ```
2. Add a refresh policy for the last 2 weeks that updates hourly:

   ```
   SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('latest_forecast_15_min',
       start_offset => INTERVAL '2 WEEKS',
       end_offset => INTERVAL '1 HOUR',
       schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 h');
   ```
3. Select data from the Continuous Aggregate:

   ```
   SELECT
   dt_start,
   fc_id,
   fc_power_supplier_id,
   fc_power_type_id,
   fc_kwh_last
   FROM latest_forecast_15_min;
   ```

For my example, this reduced the query time from `~13 seconds` to `~2 seconds` and provides the flexibility of even adding more aggregates for different query types such as groupings or time intervals.